# Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: context in

Tags: magento2, product, shopping-cart

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: context in `/home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php` on line 37

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;
class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface {
 const CACHE_TAG = 'mr_dukaaniatest';
protected $_cacheTag = 'mr_dukaaniatest';
protected $_eventPrefix = 'mr_dukaaniatest';



protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee.php');
}

/**
 * Collect grand total address amount
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
 * @return $this
 */

   protected $_feeFactory;




public function __construct(
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\FeeFactory $feeFactory
        ) {
              parent::__construct($context);

    $this->_feeFactory = $feeFactory;

}

public function collect(

) {
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);



}






public function getIdentities()
{
    $identities = [
        self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId(),
    ];
    if ($this->hasDataChanges() || $this->isDeleted()) {
        $identities[] = Product::CACHE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_TAG . '_' . $this->getId();
    }
    return $identities;
}



 public function fetch() {      
    $fee = $this->_feeFactory->create();
    $collection = $fee->getCollection();
    foreach($collection as $item){
        \Zend_Debug::dump($item->getData());
    }
    exit();
}

  public function execute()
{
    $fee = $this->_feeFactory->create();
    $collection = $fee->getCollection();
    foreach($collection as $item){
        \Zend_Debug::dump($item->getData());
    }
    exit();
}

/**
 * Get Subtotal label
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getLabel() {
    return __('Fee');
}
```

}

Comment: Please run bin/magento setup:di:compile then check.

Comment: after run this command still getting this issue

Comment: I think you did not use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context in your constructor if not please do and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add parent dependencies in your **public function __construct()**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role $resource,
    \Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\Collection $resourceCollection,
    \Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\FeeFactory $feeFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    $this->_feeFactory = $feeFactory;
}
```

Then remove your **generated** folder, clean **cache** and check again.

Comment: facing this error
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Registry, none given, called in /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php on line 37 and defined in

Comment: Remove your generated and cache folders and check again.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Check and let me know if you still face any error.

Comment: now i am not able to login my admin panel

Comment: That might be the different issue.

Comment: but after insert this code i face that issue

Comment: check your log and report files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83985/discussion-between-dinesh-yadav-and-jhon-jhon-doe).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace your constructor and need to clear generation.
Below I have added constructor code please update it in your file and check after that.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
```

Still you have any query let me know.

Comment: facing this issue
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee.php does not exist

Comment: when you getting this error ?

Comment: on login admin panel or add product in shopping cart

Comment: have you define any resourse model for it ? if no then you have to create resourse model for it

Comment: i have created module for it